# Cannot access appsettings.json from class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been following this tutorial in order to get access to my appsettings.json from my MVC project inside my class library.
[geek-tutorial](https://geeksarray.com/blog/read-appsettings-json-in-net-core-class-library-using-dependency-injection)

I have a class as such in my class library

```
using dapper;

public class SqlDataAccess : IConfigManager
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public SqlDataAccess(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this._configuration = configuration;
    }

    public List<T> LoadData<T>(string sql)
    {
        using (IDbConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            return cnn.Query<T>(sql).ToList();
        }
    }

    public int SaveData<T>(string sql, T data)
    {
        using (IDbConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            return cnn.Execute(sql, data);
        }
    }

    public string GetConnectionString(string connectionName = "URLShortnerDB")
    {
        return this._configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionName);
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IConfigManager
{
    string GetConnectionString(string connectionName);
}
```

I have added `services.AddSingleton<IConfigManager, SqlDataAccess>();` in my mvc startup.cs

However now I would like to use my `SqlDataAccess` class and call methods from another class e.g:

```
public static class ShortUrlProcessor
{
    
    public static ShortURLModel GetOriginalURL(string shortUrl)
    {        
        string sql = $@"SELECT * FROM dbo.shorturl WHERE shortUrl = '{ shortUrl }'";
        var originalURLEnum = SqlDataAccess.LoadData<ShortURLModel>(sql); //<--- problem
        return originalURLEnum.First();
    }
}
```

However `SqlDataAccess` is not instantiated, and in order to do `var _sqldataaccess = SqlDataAccess()` I need to pass in a parameter as defined in the constructor of the class. I do not know what to pass in? I do not have any IconfigurationManager in this `ShortUrlProcessor` class. I understand the reason of doing this is dependancy injection, however I am still not grasping how this all works?

Comment: Make ShortUrlProcessor be non-static, then do the same constructor injector pattern that you followed in order for the SqlDataAccess class to receive an IConfiguration instance. And you'll probably need to register ShortUrlProcessor with your IoC container. You seem to be new to the Dependency Injection concept - I highly recommend [Deep Dive Into Dependency Injection And Writing Quality Decoupled Code by Miguel Castro](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412). It's a very useful resource for helping get those concepts down.

Comment: A good general bit of guidance to follow is to avoid static classes and avoid directly invoking the constructor of objects via the "new" keyword (except for perhaps dumb DTO objects). That helps keep your methods structured properly for Dependency Injection, and ultimately so that they're unit testable.

Comment: Your code is probably vulnerable to SQL Injection attack. (Almost) Never use string concatenation to form SQL queries. That is a vector for untrusted input to become part of the SQL statements. Instead, you should use parameterized queries. [This page](https://bobby-tables.com/csharp) explains how to safely execute SQL using ADO.NET, Entity Framework, or Dapper.

Comment: @mason thank you for the commennt, I have removed the static from everything inside ShortUrlProcessor however I did not fully grasp how this is helping, I am indeed very new to dependancy injection and ASP.NET in general. Any chance your first comment could be broken down into further steps? Thanks. EDIT: thanks for the deep dive video tip

Comment: If your class is static, then you can't utilize a static constructor for normal dependency injection (via constructor injection), so it can't easily utilize objects that have been created by the DI container. And being static forces other classes to refer to it directly, which violates the Dependency Inversion Principle in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID). Other classes that need to GetOriginalUrl should be code against an abstraction (an interface) rather than a concrete implementation (a class). You did it properly with SqlDataAccess and IConfiguration.

Comment: @mason you sir, have opened a can of worms for me. I am going to try breaking down my issue: I changed ShortUrlProcessor to non static, I still cannot use SqlDataAccess as it is expecting an instantiated object, thats problem nr1. Secondly, now that ShortUrlProcessor isnt static, how do I call the methods inside that class from my controller in my MVC application?

Comment: You gotta follow the pattern! Like I said, you did it properly with SqlDataAccess. So something like `services.AddTransient<IShortUrlProcessor, ShortUrlProcessor)`, then your controller's constructor should accept an IShortUrlProcessor via it's constructor, just like how SqlDataAccess takes in an IConfiguration via its constructor.

Comment: gotcha, I created a IShortUrlProcessor and implemented it in ShortUrlProcessor. I added it in startup.cs services and my controller is no longer complaining. Thanks. I am sorry I keep making you repeat yourself, so how do I now make ShortUrlProcessor access the methods inside SqlDataAccess (both of the classes are in my class library and neither are static). 
SqlDataAccess takes IConfiguration as its constructor and ShortUrlProcessor currently has no constructor

Comment: @mason nevermind, I followed the pattern once more and its working now :) Thanks for bearing with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close, but you need to fix a few things. SqlDataAccess implements IConfigManager. Why? What's that providing? Instead, you should have it implement an interface that allows it to expose the functionality other classes depend on.

```
public interface ISqlDataAccess
{
    List<T> LoadData<T>(string sql);

    int SaveData<T>(string sql, T data);  
}
```

Change your SqlDataAccess class to implement this interface...

```
public class SqlDataAccess : ISqlDataAccess
```

And of course, wire this up with your DI container.

```
services.AddTransient<ISqlDataAccess, SqlDataAccess>();
```

Now, any class that needs to run SQL can take a dependency on the ISqlDataAccess interface, utilizing constructor injection to get an instance of ISqlDataAccess. Since we've told the DI container to provide a SqlDataAccess instance when the ISqlDataAccess dependency is present, it will all wire up nicely in your app.

Then we have the issue with ShortUrlProcessor. You declared that class as static. That's bad, because it makes it difficult for it to use constructor injection to get its dependencies, and any other class that needs to invoke its methods has to do so directly, rather than via an abstraction. That violates the Dependency Inversion Principle of [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID). And since we should always strive to write SOLID code because of the maintainability and testability, we need to fix that.

```
public class ShortUrlProcessor : IShortUrlProcessor
{    
    readonly ISqlDataAccess _dataAccess;

    public ShortUrlProcessor(ISqlDataAccess dataAccess)
    {
        _dataAccess = dataAccess;
    }
    
    public ShortURLModel GetOriginalURL(string shortUrl)
    {        
        string sql = $@"SELECT * FROM dbo.shorturl WHERE shortUrl = '{ shortUrl }'";
        var originalURLEnum = _dataAccess.LoadData<ShortURLModel>(sql); //<--- problem
        return originalURLEnum.First();
    }
}
```

And we'll need an interface so other classes don't have to depend directly on ShortUrlProcessor...

```
public interface IShortUrlProcessor
{
    ShortURLModel GetOriginalURL(string shortUrl);
}
```

And of course, we need to register it with our DI container.

```
services.AddTransient<IShortUrlProcessor, ShortUrlProcessor>();
```

Then any class that needs to access the functionality of ShortUrlProcessor can do so via the abstraction IShortUrlProcessor. You mentioned you have a controller calling this, so let's wire that up too.

```
public class MyController()
{
    readonly IShortUrlProcessor _shortUrlProcessor;

    public MyController(IShortUrlProcessor shortUrlProcessor)
    {
        _shortUrlProcessor = shortUrlProcessor;
    }

    public ActionResult SomeActionMethod()
    {
        var model = _shortUrlProcessor.GetOriginalURL("asdf");
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

We don't have to create an interface for the controller, because the controller will be called by the framework. And we don't have to wire up the controller with the DI container, because the framework handles that for us.

By doing all this, we can easily test individual methods in isolation. There's still some improvements to be made (the SQL Injection attack I mentioned in the comments needs to be fixed), but it's a good step in the right direction.

Comment: @CodeMuppet Your SqlDataAccess is a thin wrapper over Dapper. It's not providing you very much. Have you thought about using the Repository Pattern? Instead of exposing generic LoadData and SaveData methods, you could create a UrlRepository class, and it would have methods like LoadUrlViaShortUrl(string shorUrl) and SaveUrl etc. That keeps the SQL implementation details from leaking into ShortUrlProcessor, which shouldn't have to care about how the IUrlRepository is accessed. The way you have it now, it's what we call a "leaky abstraction".

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. Are you simply saying create another layer between sqldataccess and shorturlprocessor called LoadUrlViaShortUrl, where I store all the specific queries which I am writing inside shorturlprocessor?

Comment: @CodeMuppet No, not another layer. A replacement of an existing layer. Your SqlDataAccess class is a thin wrapper around Dapper, and it's a leaky abstraction. Get rid of that, and replace it with a new class (and interface) such as SqlServerUrlRepository and IUrlRepository. Have your ShortUrlProcessor depend on IUrlRepository. That way ShortUrlProcessor doesn't have to know about *how* the data is accessed, and the SQL implementation details don't end up leaking into the ShortUrlProcessor. The SQL statements for saving/loading should be in SqlServerUrlRepository.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks again